# Removing duplicate code from overriden enums

Tags: java, enums

I have a `DP enum` with `A` and `B` `enum` constants that initially had different implementations of the `abstract` method `someMethod()`. Ideally, we'd merge `A` and `B` into one `enum` constant. However, for business reasons, that's not an option. I'm trying to figure out a way to make `enum` constants `A` and `B` to share the same abstract method `someMethod()` implementation.

```
public enum DP {
    A {
        @Override
        public void someMethod(){
            // Duplicate code
        }
    },
    B {
        @Override
        public void someMethod(){
            // Duplicate code
        }
    },
    C {
        @Override
        public void someMethod(){
            // Different code
        }
    };

    public abstract void someMethod();
}
```

Comment: Other than putting the duplicated code in a separate function, and having A and B call _that_ function I'm fairly certain there's no clean way to do due this due to your restriction not allowing you to consolidate A and B. Could you possibly elaborate what the reason is you can't consolidate A and B? If so, maybe an alternative solution could be reached.

Comment: @EwanBrown Both enums are called from many teams beyond my own. There's no reason technical reason we can't combine them but I'm not sure the small benefit from removing one enum for code readability is worth making sure it doesn't break things from other teams.

Comment: I would likely go with Oboe's answer — implement `someMethod()` instead of making it abstract — but another possibility would be to have A call B's someMethod ... `A { public void someMethod() { B.someMethod(); } }` (or have B call A's)

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question correctly, instead of an `abstract` method, you can add duplicate code in the method and override the method only in `C`:

```
public enum DP {
    A,
    B,
    C {
        @Override
        public void someMethod() {
            // Different code
            System.out.println("C");
        }
    };
    
    public void someMethod() {
        //Duplicate code
        System.out.println("AB");
    }
}
```

Then:

```
DP.A.someMethod();
DP.B.someMethod();
DP.C.someMethod();
```

Output:

```
AB
AB
C
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using Java 8 or above, you can solve this with *default interface methods*.

Define an interface with your `someMethod`, and add a *default implementation*:

```java
interface SomeInterface {
    default void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Some default method");
    }
}
```

Then let the enum implement the interface:

```java
public enum DP implements SomeInterface { ... }
```

Voila. You can just use it like you'd expect:

```java
DP.A.someMethod();
DP.B.someMethod();
DP.C.someMethod();
```

<kbd>[Online demo](https://ideone.com/FCp5FL)</kbd>